# MDX - Sum at lowest time, then Max it out

Tags: olap, mdx, rolap

I have;

- a Time dimension (*Year, Month, Day, Hour*),
- a Product dimension (*Product, Feature*)
- and a User dimension (*User*)

The measure I have available is: *Used* (Number of features that are in use)

What I want to do, is to display the **Max** of concurrent usage. (This would be the **Max** of the **Sum** of *Used* for each *Feature* used by the same *User*, that happened in the same *Hour*).

Is this doable in MDX, or would I need to deal with this in my database? (That feels wrong)

Did I make self understandable? Any suggestion is welcome..

**Edit (11 Feb 10:44 Central):**

Visual explanation.. (this is what I want):

```
                               [2008 Feb 11] [2008 Feb 11, 07:00] [2008 Feb 11, 07:30]  [2008 Feb 11, 08:00]
[Feature A] [Glenn] [Used]              5               2                    1                     2
[Feature A] [Glenn] [Max Used]          3               2                    1                     2
```

**Max Used** is as you see a **Max Used Hourly**. To get this, I would need to do the Sum at the hourly level..

I'm currently using Mondrian

Answer (score 1):

From your new edits, it looks like Hour is not the leaf of your time dimension so the title of your question is not quite accurate. Since you are crossjoining feature and user in your query then something like the following might work.

MAX(EXISTING [Time].[Hour].[Hour].Members, [Measures].[Used])

Unfortunately I use Microsoft SSAS not Mondrian, so I don't know if it supports the identical syntax.

Comment: The Max would work, for a single Used - but when I have multiple, it wont work. See the new visual example..